# Pass object inside existing model object, where the new object parameters are not defined and may change

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Problem: I have a request body where I have a predefined POJO class, inside this class I need to add another object as parameter.  This new object at a given time may have random properties/attributes/params.  How can I achieve this?

```
{
 "id": "{{id}}",
 "enableTouchId": true,
 "idleLogoutMinutes": 10,
 "platformSpecificPreferences": {
  "ios": {
   "terms": "1234",
   "privacy": "12345"
  },
  "web": {
    "terms" : "abc"
  },
  "android": {
    "newProperty" : "newValue"
  }
 }
}
```

So the new object I am trying to add is platformSpecificPreferences, which when hit using rest calls might or might not have all the properties shown here, which is why I cannot use redefined POJO class for platformSpecificPreferences and create its object.

Solution I tried:
I thought of using JsonObject inside request body, which makes

```
@JsonProperty("platformSpecificPreferences")
    private JsonObject platformSpecificPreferences;
```

but the problem is, I am not able to hit the api as it doesnt accept this parameter and gives 404.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, kind must a predefined pojo for platformSpecificPreferences but in the pojo you need to ignore values that are not given in the rest call!

You can do this with a json annotation:@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) in the Pojo above the class.

Comment: All the properties will be decided on the fly, for a predefined pojo to even add ignore property annotation i will need to define these params

Comment: Are you meaning to say you do not know at all which properties you get? e.g. under web you have terms but there can be another property like smiley under the web pojo send to you?